# How to implement Material Design's Grid List using Materializecss

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material, materialize

I'm building web apps in Angular. I've been going back and forth between [Materializecss](http://materializecss.com/) and [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/examples). Overall, I prefer Materializecss which I use with [Angular2-Materialize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-materialize). Alas, Materializecss hasn't implemented Grid Lists yet and I was wondering how to implement them if I'm using Materializecss and Angular? Idealy, I'm looking for a solution that doesn't use JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I would have to come up with nested loops for each row but I had never realized that within Materializecss' grid system it looks like if you add more cols than a row can normally contain (12), the cols will actually wrap below. It will all still be contained within the same row element but visually you'll get a neatly formatted grid. Here's my HTML for example.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s2" *ngFor="let card of cards">
      <div class="card small">
        <div class="card-image">
          <img src="...">
          <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p>{{card}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
          <a href="#">This is a link</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, no nested loop. Just the one loop on the column element.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this NPM package !
https://www.npmjs.com/package/materialize-grid-list

HTML and CSS example:

```html
<div class="grid-list">
  <div class="grid-cell">
    <div class="grid-tile">
      <a href="#!"><img class="responsive-img" src="img/1.png" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell">
    <div class="grid-tile">
      <a href="#!"><img class="responsive-img" src="img/2.png" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell">
    <div class="grid-tile">
      <a href="#!"><img class="responsive-img" src="img/3.png" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell">
    <div class="grid-tile">
      <a href="#!"><img class="responsive-img" src="img/4.png" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell">
    <div class="grid-tile">
      <a href="#!"><img class="responsive-img" src="img/5.png" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell">
    <div class="grid-tile">
      <a href="#!"><img class="responsive-img" src="img/6.png" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell">
    <div class="grid-tile">
      <a href="#!"><img class="responsive-img" src="img/7.png" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid-cell">
    <div class="grid-tile">
      <a href="#!"><img class="responsive-img" src="img/8.png" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then call the JQuery plugin via :

```js
$('.grid-list').materialGrid();
```